# CakePHP hasMany not Saving

Tags: cakephp

I am working on CakePHP 2.0 and here's my code:

```
class Sheet extends AppModel{

    var $name = 'fc_sheets';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Apspent' => array(
            'className' => 'Adspent',
            'foreignKey'=> 'sheetID',
        ),
    ); 
}

class Adspent extends AppModel{

    var $name = 'fc_adspents';
    var $hasOne = 'Sheet';
    var $belongsTo = 'Sheet';

}
```

In the controller:

```
class SheetsController extends AppController{

    var $name = 'Sheets';

    function add(){
        $this->Sheet->save($this->data);
        //I have also tried this
        $this->Sheet->saveAll($this->data);
    }
}
```

Here's the debug of **`print_r($this->data)`**:

```
Array ( 
    [Adspent] => Array ( [description] => Array ( [0] => Yellow Pages ) [price] => Array ( [0] => 200 ) ) 
    [Sheet] => Array ( [adFundConst] => 2 [warrFundConst] => 1 [pst] => 8 [gst] => 5 [hst] => 13 [adspent] => 200.00 [percentAdv] => Infinity [normalSales] => 0.00 [extraSales] => 0.00 [totalSales] => 0.00 [adFund] => 0.00 [warrFund] => 0.00 [royalty] => 200.00 [tax] => 26.00 [total] => 226.00 [matTotal] => 0.00 [totalDue] => 226.00 )
)
```

But the Sheet data is the only one saving in the database not the other one.

Anyone have an idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
'dependent'=> true
```

add this in your has many relationship

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Apspent' => array(
        'className' => 'Adspent',
        'foreignKey'=> 'sheetID',
        'dependent'=> true, 
    ),
);
```

my be solve you problem...

Comment: $actAs = 'Sheet'... add this line Adspent class... may be help

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused due to the data in Adspent's `description` and `price` fields are arrays.

You have this:

```
Array ( 
    [Adspent] => Array (
        [description] => Array ( [0] => Yellow Pages )
        [price] => Array ( [0] => 200 ) 
    ) 
    [Sheet] => Array ( 
        [adFundConst] => 2
        [warrFundConst] => 1 
        [pst] => 8 
        [gst] => 5 
        [hst] => 13
        [adspent] => 200.00 
        [percentAdv] => Infinity 
        [normalSales] => 0.00 
        [extraSales] => 0.00
        [totalSales] => 0.00 
        [adFund] => 0.00 
        [warrFund] => 0.00 
        [royalty] => 200.00 
        [tax] => 26.00 
        [total] => 226.00 
        [matTotal] => 0.00 
        [totalDue] => 226.00
    )
)
```

Try to change your form so your form posts data without arrays in the `description` and `price` fields like this:

```
Array ( 
    [Adspent] => Array (
        [description] => Yellow Pages
        [price] => 200 
    ) 
    [Sheet] => Array ( 
        [adFundConst] => 2
        [warrFundConst] => 1 
        [pst] => 8 
        [gst] => 5 
        [hst] => 13
        [adspent] => 200.00 
        [percentAdv] => Infinity 
        [normalSales] => 0.00 
        [extraSales] => 0.00
        [totalSales] => 0.00 
        [adFund] => 0.00 
        [warrFund] => 0.00 
        [royalty] => 200.00 
        [tax] => 26.00 
        [total] => 226.00 
        [matTotal] => 0.00 
        [totalDue] => 226.00
    )
)
```

And then to save, try:

```
$this->Sheet->saveAssociated($this->request->data)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned `hasMany` relation then your array structure should look like this.

```
Array ( 
    [Adspent] => Array (
        [description] => Yellow Pages
        [price] => 200 
    ) 
    [Sheet] => 
[0] => Array ( 
        [adFundConst] => 2
        [warrFundConst] => 1 
        [pst] => 8 
        [gst] => 5 
)
[1] => Array ( 
        [adFundConst] => 2
        [warrFundConst] => 1 
        [pst] => 8 
        [gst] => 5 
    )
)
```

Try to form array in the above format and see.
For more details please refer http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1032/Saving-Related-Model-Data-hasOne-hasMany-belongsTo